# declerative_authorization on User problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

I am trying to block all default methods except create and update in my users controller using declerative_authorization. But at the time I add filter_resource_access or filter_access_to into my usersController i always get "Couldn't find User without an ID". Anyone care to explain why this could be happening?

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
  filter_resource_access
```

def new
    @user = User.new
  end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Account registered!"
      redirect_to account_url
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

def show
    @user = @current_user
  end

def edit
    @user = @current_user
  end

def update
    @user = @current_user # makes our views "cleaner" and more consistent
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "Account updated!"
      redirect_to account_url
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the `@user` variable before the `filter_access_to` call with a `before_filter` as declarative_authorization tries to access `@user` when you call `filter_access_to`.

```
before_filter :set_user
filter_access_to :all

...

protected

def set_user
  @user = @current_user
end
```

Maybe you are setting the `attribute_check` parameter to `true` in your `filter_access_to` call? I have a similar controller and I don't really need the `before_filter`.

Another thing that might be causing it is a `using_access_control` call in your `User` model.